# Do files saved locally via Google Colab persist indefinitely?

Tags: google-colaboratory

If I execute the following command in a Google Colab code cell:

```
!wget https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer -P "/content"
```

a file is saved in my local `/content` folder. Will the file remain there indefinitely until I explicitly delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this blurb](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#idle-timeouts) titled *How long can notebooks run in Colab?* from the official Google Colaboratory FAQ I conclude that with a free Colab account a Colab notebook's runtime environment, and with it all files saved in the file system associated with it, are deleted after 12 hours from the moment the runtime was first connected to the notebook.

Additionally, you can manually delete the current runtime environment via the *Runtime* menu. If you do so, all files saved in the file system associated with this environment will be deleted and won't appear in the next runtime environment that will be connected to your notebook.